# Given a real $x$ and an integer $N \gt 1$, prove that there exist integers $h$ and $k$ with $0 \lt k \le N$ such that $|kx-h|\lt 1/N$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Given a real $x$ and an integer $N \gt 1$, prove that there exist integers $h$ and $k$ with $0 \lt k \le N$ such that $|kx-h|\lt 1/N$. Hint. Consider the $N+1$ numbers $tx-[tx]$ for $t=0,1,2,\dots, N$ and show that some pair differs by at most $1/N$.

I'm trying to prove this hint. Let $a_t=tx-[tx]$ for $t=0,1,2,\dots, N$, and assume that for every different pair $|a_i-a_j| \ge 1/N$.

I can't lead to a contradiction from this. I would greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score -1):

PLEASE delete, I misread the (conditions of the) OP.

Comment: This will not (usually) give you a $k$ that is smaller than $N$.

Comment: What is wrong with this? It is a sketch, nottan answer. You know, you get chided for giving afull answer and downvoted for a hint. Seriously.

Comment: @EricWofsey: But you _can_ go as far as necessary along the expansion and find such a $k$, guaranteed to work. I did say $k $ _large-enough_.

Comment: Sorry, I did not read that condition, my bad.